# Why does my Qt 4.5 app open a console window under Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, console, mingw, qt-creator

I've been playing around with Qt Creator 4.5 under Linux. My application builds just fine under Linux, but if I build in Windows, the app always opens a console window at startup.

Can I stop it doing that?

I'm building using the default MinGW setup, perhaps that is related. If need be I can build with Visual Studio, but I'd like to understand what is happening first...

**Edit**: I just created a simple test GUI app with Qt Creator under Windows and it didn't exhibit this behaviour. Either this behaviour has occurred because of the way the project was created under linux, or there is something my app does which causes the console window to appear. Will post details when I diagnose it in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is that including the Qt testlib causes the console to appear. Removing it makes it go away.

To explain further, if your .pro file adds testlib to QT, e.g.

```
QT += sql \
    webkit \
    network \
    testlib
```

then the final link step is carried out with a line like this

```
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup 
   -Wl,-enable-auto-import 
   -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc 
   -mthreads 
   -Wl 
   -Wl,-subsystem,console 
   -o debug\MyApp.exe object_script.MyApp.Debug  
   -L"c:\Qt\2009.01\qt\lib"  
   -lglu32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lQtWebKitd4 -lQtTestd4 
   -lQtSqld4 -lQtGuid4 -lQtNetworkd4 -lQtCored
```

We've wound up using the console subsystem! I presume using testlib forces this to happen so that the test output has somewhere to go.

If we now edit the .pro file and remove the reference to testlib and rebuild, we get a link step like this

```
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup 
   -Wl,-enable-auto-import 
   -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc 
   -mthreads 
   -Wl 
   -Wl,-subsystem,windows 
   -o debug\Ammotin.exe object_script.Ammotin.Debug  
   -L"c:\Qt\2009.01\qt\lib" 
   -lglu32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -lQtWebKitd4 
   -lQtSqld4  -lQtGuid4 -lQtNetworkd4 -lQtCored4
```

Yay! subsystem is windows, no more console window.

Comment: Hello, I don't have `testlib` in my .pro, and I have the same problem

Comment: This flag worked in Qt 5.7 `QT.testlib.CONFIG -= console` But this `CONFIG -= console` doesn't work.

Answer (score 28):

For those who have this issue using **CMake** under **Windows** (see [Amoo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760323/why-does-my-qt-4-5-app-open-a-console-window-under-windows/36528717?noredirect=1#comment110396547_36528717)), here's a solution [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-March/020576.html).

In short, you need to add `WIN32` to your `add_executable()` statements:

```
add_executable(GuiApplication WIN32 src/main.cpp)
```

For further details, see the CMake documentation on [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) and [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE).

Comment: Worked with CMake on Windows

Comment: If you are Windows and using CMake and the application is showing after terminal when you click it outside of IDE, this is the correct solution for that.

Comment: Thanks @AmooHesam for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Comment: Alternatively CMake `set_target_properties(yourtarget PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON)` command is available

Answer (score 11):

I think that this is not a solution for this specific answer (besides it is 4 years later),
but I think that many people landing in this thread will be looking for this setting:

Projects > Build and Run > Run Settings > Run > **[x] Run in terminal**

De-select it and run your GUI from QtCreator without an extra Terminal window. Terminal output will be then embedded in the IDE.

Comment: Thank you, this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Glad it helped somebody :)

Comment: just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You will want to make sure the -mwindows switch is provided.

**Edit:**

alternatively, you can go into your makefile and add this to your linker flags:

```
-Wl,-subsystem,windows
```

Comment: Is that something I can set within Qt Creator?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your .pro file doesn't add `console` to the variable `CONFIG`. You can do this by adding

```
CONFIG -= console
```

somewhere at the end of your .pro file. If `CONFIG` contains `console` a window pops up every time you start the program, and this is also used when printing debug output. Thus, adding `console` can be useful when debugging a program. Otherwise you'd need to use tools like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) to show the output of the `qDebug()` calls.

Answer (score 4):

I use cmake instead of qmake.  I used set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-mwindows")
seems as though 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-mwindows
in your .pro file would do the same.

Comment: This works for a gcc toolchain, but what about with using the MSVC compiler? (it says "unknown option -mwindows").

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your linker settings are set for a console app.  You could try setting the linker to use the /subsystem:windows option.  The option for console applications is /subsystem:console.  If you build your project in Visual Studio, create a Win32 Project.  Don't create a Win32 Console App.    The option under Visual Studio for setting the subsystem is under Project Settings->Linker->System->SubSystem.  Select Windows(/subsystem:windows).

I took a look into how to do this with MinGW/gcc.  The online docs for [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html) shows the different options for Windows targets.  Like other have stated, the option you are looking for is -mwindows.  The option -mwindows creates a windowed app.  It seems like your current setting is -mconsole.  The option -mconsole produces a console app.  This is a linker option. I'm not familiar with Qt Creator but I'm guessing it has a similar way to view project settings like Visual Studio has.

Comment: These options are for the Microsoft linker.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to understand why this occurs using Mingw though.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: `Projects --> Run` and uncheck `Run in terminal` checkbox

Answer (score 1):

By default the linker assumes you want a console application.

The fix is to add "-mwindows" to your compiler's argument list, and this will also invisibly add the required libraries (-lkernel32, -lgdi32, etc.). You'll probably need to change from main() to WinMain() as the entry point.

**RE: your Edit:** the Qt build system uses "spec" files to add variables, you can find them in $QTDIR/qt/mkspecs. When you create a new Windows app in QCreator, it sets the default spec to "win32-g++", which automatically sets the correct variables (windows app, linker flags, etc.).

When you made the project under Linux, it used another spec and that caused your issue. You can see the current spec in the "yourproject.pro.user" file.

Comment: OK, I'm not all that familiar with Qt. A WinMain is required for GUI apps in Windows, so the framework probably implements WinMain() itself and calls your main() behind the scenes. 

The rest of the post stands, though.

Answer (score 0):

Qt/2009.05/qt/mkspecs/win32-g++
edit file qmake.conf
modify line
QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE = -Wl,-subsyetem,console
to
QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE = -Wl,-subsyetem,windows

and modify your ???.pro file (example add new line or space)
and compiling
it`s working ok

Answer (score 0):

For MSVC compiler on windows do this:

Open Makefile.Release file in build directory. Find 'LFLAGS' and on the right side of that, find 'SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE', and replace 'CONSOLE' by 'WINDOWS'. If previous exe file exists, delete it and build project again.

(I tested with Qt 6.5 and MSVC 2022)