# How to avoid console window in Qt application, even after Including "testlib" package (for qWait()) in my .pro file?

Tags: qt, qt4

Hallo everyone,

I have gone through various threads on this topic but, nothing seems to solve my particular problem. Including testlib, makes the console window appear and there I didnot find any option to suppress this behaviour.

But my application still demands testlib to be present (because i badly wanted to use QTest::qWait() method), and no console window to appear. I tried a few options from the other threads but nothing is working. what should i do to suppress this console window even after using 'testlib"?

The options I tried are

1. adding CONFIG -= console to my .pro file.

   ```
       QT += gui \    
           xml \
           core \
           testlib    
       CONFIG += qt \
           windows \
           uitools \
           release        
       CONFIG -= console        
       LIBS += extern/ftd2xx.lib        
       RC_FILE = res/AC-Core.rc        
       QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall \
   ```
2. editing the qmake.conf file, the lines

   ```
   QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE = -Wl,-subsystem,console, to    
   QMAKE_LFLAGS_CONSOLE = -Wl,-subsystem,windows
   ```

Any other ideas to suppress the appearing of console window are welcome?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/760323/13767

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `QTest` to get the functionality of `QTest::qWait()`. If you look at the source code for `qWait()` you can see how it works and implement this function yourself:

```
inline static void qWait(int ms)
{
    Q_ASSERT(QCoreApplication::instance());

    QTime timer;
    timer.start();
    do {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, ms);
        QTest::qSleep(10);
    } while (timer.elapsed() < ms);
}
```

Comment: Or, even better, use local QEventLoop and QTimer::singleShot on event loop's quit() slot.