# Qt5 opens console with gui applications

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, console

I use Qt5.2 (git) with MSVC13 on Windows. If I build any application (even the templates) it always opens in a cmd.exe window. I tried different Qt versions and different compilers (even MinGW), but I always have the same problem. 
If however, I start the application using the green play button in QtDesigner it opens without a cmd window. 
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760323/why-does-my-qt4-5-app-open-a-console-window-under-windows) I tried "CONFIG -= console" with no effect. Also I dont use testlib.
In my qmake.conf I see the line "QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS"

Does this depend on the dll files I put in the application directory? QtDesigner does not copy any dlls to the build folder, however it sets some environment variables. To run the application from a separate folder I copy the corresponding dlls from the Qt lib folder into the applications exe folder.

Any ideas for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Do you happen to use qdebug?

Comment: No, i don't think so, it also happend with template projects and using the release dll's

Comment: Try using dependency walker - you might have "global" dll somewhere. I don't have MSVC13 so I can't investigate that. Do you use Express edition or a full featured one?

Comment: Im using a full featured version of MSVC13, however Im only using the MSVC compiler but QtCreator as IDE.
PS: Please replace QtDesigner with QtCreator in my previous post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this took a while, but i finally found the solution here:
[Hide console of Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139637/hide-console-of-windows-application)

I had to replace the main entry function:

Replace the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     // your code*
}
```

by

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char*, int nShowCmd)
{
    int argc = 0;
    QApplication app( argc, 0 );
 }
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

In MSVC 2013 go to your project properties/ linker and change from:

```
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

To:

```
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
```

It worked for me.

[image: TODO]

Comment: I tried to set the "QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" flag separately as additional make flag from QtDesigner, however it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Do you use MSVC or QtCreator? You said MSVC in the question.

Comment: I use MSVC13 compiler with QtCreator as IDE. However the problem consists with different compilers now. Might it be a problem that I'm using the SVN version of Qt? This problem didn't occur with a precompiled version of Qt with MSVC12 on my old setup.

Answer (score 0):

Is the checkbox `run in terminal` checked?

[image]

Comment: No, run in terminal is not checked. However I'm experiencing exactly the opposite effect. If I start my program from QTDesigner it does not open a console. If however I start it from the windows explorer as a standalone program it starts the console.

Comment: @DayAndNight did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760323/why-does-my-qt4-5-app-open-a-console-window-under-windows?lq=1) ?

Comment: Yep, thanks, I tired the suggestions stated in my original post but unfortunately the problem still consists.