# Why is my Qt GUI application started by console one?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, deployment, console-application

I haven't asked that, I created a Qt GUI application that when on release, outside Qt creator it does generate an executable which starts a console application that then start my GUI application. I've used Qt several times before and it never happend.

My .pro file goes as the following:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets webkitwidgets network script

TARGET = downloader
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11
```

and the deployment like this:

```
windeployqt --webkit2 --release full_path\to\release\downloader.exe
```

What am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK this only happens if you use the "console subsystem", in VS you can change this by passing `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` in the linker settings, maybe you need something similar for Qt?

Comment: Is this on windows? If yes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/760323/6525260)

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882500/1597714)